# How to use weather API in a website

Tags: javascript, web-services, api

I am developing a weather application and i am trying to use API from worldweatheronline.com website . but my question here is how do i start to use this weather API in my website. as i have already read a question from SO and was not clear about the solution [How to integrate the weather api into my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18311355/how-to-integrate-the-weather-api-into-my-website) . So please help me how to start using these API using Javascript. any examples would be appreciated. and please do remember that i am new to web apps API usage.

the response which i got from the website is

```
Request URI
  http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/search.ashx?q=Chennai&format=json&key=53jjtnrm9d5jucpmxyyhj7vn
```

Request Headers
       {
       "X-Originating-Ip": "14.140.167.22"
       }

```
Response Headers

     {
   "Age": "0",
   "Cache-Control": "public, no-cache=\"Set-Cookie\", max-age=120",
   "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  "Date": "Mon, 16 Sep 2013 09:02:34 GMT",
  "Server": "Microsoft-IIS/7.5",
  "X-Aspnet-Version": "4.0.30319",
  "X-Cache": "MISS",
  "X-Mashery-Responder": "prod-j-worker-eu-west-1a-96.mashery.com",
  "X-Powered-By": "UKFast Webcelerator",
  "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
  "Connection": "keep-alive"
```

}

```
 Response Body
      {
    "search_api": {
    "result": [{
        "areaName": [{
            "value": "Chennai"
        }],
        "country": [{
            "value": "India"
        }],
        "latitude": "13.083",
        "longitude": "80.283",
        "population": "0",
        "region": [{
            "value": "Tamil Nadu"
        }],
        "weatherUrl": [{
            "value": "http:\/\/www.worldweatheronline.com\/Chennai-weather\/Tamil-Nadu\/IN.aspx"
        }]
    }]
   }
   }
```

Comment: You need to make AJAX call to your RESTful web service from your application.

Comment: @PrasannaAarthi: any examples ?

Answer (score 1):

Please visit http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ ,for how to make a call to a web service.

For your weather API, please register , get the keys

```
  $.ajax(
{
    Type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=London&format=json&num_of_days=5&key=yourkey",

    success: function (msg) {
        $("#success").text(msg);
    }
});
```

This is an example for getting local weather.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this via php:

```
$url="http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=[LOCATION]&format=json&num_of_days=5&key=[YOUR_KEY]";
$json=file_get_contents($url);
$data=json_decode($json,true);
//var_dump($data);
echo $data['data']['weather'][0]['tempMaxF']."<br />";
```

That's what I'm using because I just have it run on load and I'm not using it in an app; just on a web page.